# Applications of category theory and topoi/topos theory in reality

Tags: category-theory, applications, topos-theory

I am an amateur mathematician with an interest in the subjects named in the title. I have recently come to understand that my B.A. in math gives me absolutely no qualification at all in the Swedish job market. Hence I will try to compliment it with something else. I'd like to remain as close as I can to the pure world so now I'm wondering if anybody has any idea of related yet practical fields.

Edit:
I am thinking (very vaguely) that there might be something along the lines of organizing database into functional and searchable structures.

Regards,

Comment: @CliveNewstead, Yes I do

Comment: If I am not mistaken, this is (so far) the one and only question on the site with both tags _category-theory_ and _applications_.

Comment: I don't know if that's funny or sad

Comment: So all students in Sweden with BA degrees in math alone are wandering around without a job? How are those with degrees in history, philosophy, or physics doing?

Comment: @KCd, not good i fear. Some become teachers. It's not the same in your country?

Comment: I'm in the US. Math majors may pursue careers, if not in teaching, in a financial area (perhaps insurance, as actuaries) or a job that requires a good knowledge of probability and statistics (e.g., forecasting of all kinds). So students in Sweden are mostly trying to major in marketing if they're not going into engineering or medicine?

Comment: @KCd
Statistics from 2010 paints the following picture:
1: Medicine,  19k degrees 
2: Law, Trade & Admin, 16k degrees
3: Teaching, 13k degrees
4: Engineering, 11k degrees
5: Science, Math & Data, 4k degrees
6: Arts and Social Science: 3k degrees
7: Agriculture, 500 degrees

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I wrote a reply to a related question describing applications of category theory to programming, but it's on http://mathoverflow.net I could copy it here, but that might not be considered ethical so here is a [link](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/4235/relating-category-theory-to-programming-language-theory/4274#4274).

Also, check out the work by David Spivak on [categorical databases](http://math.mit.edu/~dspivak/informatics/talks/CTDBIntroductoryTalk).

Comment: tanks, seems to be somewhat what i was looking for

Answer (score 4):

I can present you with a personal example.

I am creating a mathematical model which independently lends itself to a algebraic interpretation using the Dirac's Bra-Ket notation and also could be visualized as a digraph.

So up until a few months ago, I was having real troubles placing the fundamental model upon which these two viewpoints presented themselves as one entity. They came from the same phenomenology and they purport to describe the same, so which one was better and which one should I focus on to really understand what was going on?

Category theory made that question obsolete when I realized that both of these incarnations were mere categorical reflections of an overlying categorical space. Thus I realized that the algebra was a cograph and digraphs where the graph (as Lawvere and Schnuel define a cograph in Conceptual Math p. 280) and my work has taken off since! :)