# Real world applications of category theory

Tags: category-theory, applications

I was reading some basic information from Wiki about category theory and honestly speaking I have a very weak knowledge about it. As it sounds interesting, I will go into the theory to learn more if it is actually useful in practice.

My question is to know if category theory has some applications in practice, namely in engineering problems.

I have already read this [Applications of category theory and topoi/topos theory in reality](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/280166/applications-of-category-theory-and-topoi-topos-theory-in-reality)

and the answers are only about programming which are not very interesting from my point of view.

Any comments are welcomed, thanks in advance.

Comment: Related: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/89086, http://mathoverflow.net/questions/83363, http://www.quora.com/What-are-some-real-life-applications-of-category-theory ... are you also interested in the use of category theory in philosophy?

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg thanks for the links.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg Though this is quite a bit late, I'm actually quite interested in the use of category theory in philosophy. If you know of any work you could point me towards I would be greatly appreciative.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Category theory is far from the engineering textbook level, for now. On the research level, there are a lot of instances where category theory is applied in engineering context, from electrical to biomedical engineering. Beware though: these usually come from people who try to apply category theory, rather than from people who try to solve an engineering problem and find category theory useful in doing so.

Comment: I agree that it seem a bit complicated and the person who can really apply it should be in the field. However, in most of the cases they are also too much in the theory and even if they find something it is barely understandable by engineers.

Comment: @Manos +1, I hear you. For example, Wadler showed that call-by-value is dual to call-by-name.. . As my former boss Lyndon Johnson used to say, therefore what?

Comment: It's in the software engineering textbooks.

Comment: @sigpe: Can you point to one such textbook? I am interested.

Answer (score 37):

The blog entry ["Why Category Theory Matters"](http://rs.io/why-category-theory-matters/) by Robert Seaton ends with a quite impressive reference list of applications of category theory to the sciences:

- Category theory has been used to study [grammar and human language](http://reyes-reyes.com/1999/06/01/count-nouns-mass-nouns-and-their-transformations-a-category-theoretic-unified-semantics/).
- In [building a spreadsheet application](http://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/0803/0803.2027.pdf).
- As a [descriptive tool in neuroscience](http://arxiv.org/PS_cache/math/pdf/0306/0306223v1.pdf).
- In the [analysis and design of cognitive neural network architectures](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.32.2635).
- In programming languages, especially [Haskell and most famously monads](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Category_theory), but also, for instance, a [typed assembly language](http://www.cs.cornell.edu/~ross/publications/italx/) and work on the [typed lambda calculus](http://www.cs.nott.ac.uk/~txa/publ/lics01.pdf).
- [Generating program optimizations](http://www.cs.cornell.edu/~ross/publications/proofgen/proofgen_tate_popl10.pdf).
- To [model systems of interacting agents](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Space-Motion-Communicating-Agents/dp/0521738334/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&s=books&qid=1283624498&sr=8-1).
- To [generalize sorting algorithms](https://www.cs.ox.ac.uk/people/ralf.hinze/publications/WGP12.pdf).
- To [understand collaborative text editing](http://arxiv.org/abs/1311.3903). See also [this blog](https://bosker.wordpress.com/2014/06/19/revisiting-on-editing-text/).
- To [understand optimal play in sequential games](http://www.cs.bham.ac.uk/~mhe/papers/selection-escardo-oliva.pdf) like chess.
- To [formalize the notion of algorithm](http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0602053v3.pdf).
- In [the study of analogy](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1023/A:1018963029743).
- As [“a language for experimental design patterns” and “a new vocabulary in which to think and communicate.”](http://math.mit.edu/~dspivak/CT4S.pdf)
- In definitions of [emergence](http://www.nbi.dk/~emmeche/coPubl/97d.NABCE/ExplEmer.html) and discussions of [biology](https://golem.ph.utexas.edu/category/2007/11/category_theory_and_biology.html).

Comment: thx for the references.

Answer (score 12):

I recently wrote some software to simulate a real world physical system to show that a hardware technology has a chance of doing what we want it to do. That project has grown to a pretty substantial piece of engineering with sizable budget. I wrote the simulation in a programming language whose syntax could be described as the "internal language" of a Cartesian closed category with a bunch of extensions, many of which were categorically motivated.

Sadly I eventually had to switch to Python because I couldn't find libraries for everything I wanted.

The language was Haskell.

Comment: I know I am resuscitating a very old discussion.  Still I am curious about how things went for this project of yours.  I write a lot of Python code for work and fun, but my code is more and more 'functional' because I have learned of lot of mathematics lately.  I am not trying to write a Python implementation of Haskell, but I am slowly building a library of arrows that feels nice to use.  It's not very pythonic anymore, though.  How did your transition do?

Comment: @Niriel Transition went very well. You can read about the actual project here: http://www.theverge.com/2013/9/1/4680456/google-shows-how-project-loon-could-ride-wind-currents

Answer (score 12):

This answer is also very late.  There is a recent book by David Spivak titled "Category Theory for the Sciences."  Its sole purpose is to connect the "real world" with category theory.  You can find an older draft [here](http://math.mit.edu/~dspivak/CT4S.pdf) from the authors homepage.

Comment: I think it's worth to link [their course](http://math.mit.edu/~dspivak/teaching/sp13/) — there're also links to a newer book versions.

Comment: examples from this book are not that impressive though

Answer (score 9):

I know this answer is (very) late, but I think this may be of interest. [This](http://ames.tamu.edu/A%20categorical%20theory.pdf) is the Ph.D. thesis of Professor Aaron Ames of Texas A&M which he wrote while a student at UC Berkeley. It applies category theory to hybrid systems and specifically uses category theory for the purposes of model reduction and analyzing stability in hybrid systems. It also presents some results on networked systems that are rooted in category theory.

Answer (score 7):

Seeing how software has infiltrated our lives in so many ways it seems that category theoretic applications to programming is pretty much 'real world' stuff.

Category theory is more geared up to clarifying conceptual structures, so I imagine that there isn't likely to be real world applications in a very direct way soon, and I say this as some-one who likes the general theory.

Answer (score 5):

Category theory is a good and powerful language capable of expressing various concepts of purely algebraical nature.

But it is a terrible tool for actually solving problems.

To convince yourself that the last statement is true try to think about a proof of a theorem from another branch of mathematics that depends on a category theory in a crucial, non-linguistic way. I doubt you will find any such proof. Thus it is hardly a surprising fact that you will not find any serious application of category theory in engineering problems.

On the other hand, you will find plenty of applications of category theory inside category theory. Category theory fights with problems originating in category theory, with problems of no practical relevance for mathematicians, not to mention engineers.

Comment: Because from a category theory point of view a wooden girder and a titanium girder are isomorphic and cannot (and should not) really be distinguished!

Comment: Sounds very interesting...

Comment: @Godot You are very nearly asserting that category theory has no theorems with real applications. That is false: the adjoint functor theorem gives rise to many "free" constructions in algebra.

Comment: @Zhen Lin: are those constructions impossible to perform without the notion of adjoint functor and related category theoretic results? If so, are those constructions only  known to be possible and that is all we can say about them? Are they leading to new results about already known interesting objects not directly linked with adjoints? If not: it is just another reason to consider adjoint functor theorem uninteresting for mathematicians working in fields other than category theory. By the way: we can use free constructions without knowing anything about categories.

Comment: I think it's true that there are unlikely to be applications of category theory in engineering, and I think you're right that category theory is not a tool for solving problems of a concrete / computational nature - nor is it meant to be! But I have to take issue with the claim that category theory is irrelevant to problems originating outside of category theory. The most powerful counterexample is the great strides that have been made in modern algebraic geometry after the adoption of a categorical framework by Grothendieck.

Comment: (continued) Also, I would argue that the conceptual framework in which one understands a mathematical problem is of equal importance to the technical tools used to solve it. It's true that these "linguistic" applications are where category theory excels, and that is one of the qualities that I think makes it such a nice body of mathematics.

Comment: @AlexKruckman: thank you for your comment, it is a nice "counterweight" to my answer. Let me add some commentary on the role of category theory. I do believe that a good language is often of crucial importance, becaouse when you can easily talk about something it is more likely that you will understand it. Also a good language serves as a mnemonic device allowing you not to concentrate on many irrelevant aspects. In my opinion category theory is such a language useful in talking about algebra in broad sense. But algebra (understood as algebraic aspects of mathematics) is about 1/4 of math.

Comment: (continued) I have encountered opinions of the form "take your mathematical problem, write it down in a categorical way and the category theory will help you find answers you are looking for". I think this paradigm is quite popular among categorists. In my opinion it is ridiculous to think that all diversity of mathematics can be reduced to categorical framework. Mathematics is not functorial. And algebraic manipulations are not the essence of math. Therefore while category theory is a natural language for many theories of algebraic nature it is pretty helpless against problems

Comment: (continued) where algebra is not the dominant factor. In some way I would be happy to see that a large body of math rely on categorical ideas, that such abstract nonsenses are really the essence. But we have many reasons to believe that math is not that simple.  I believe that mathematics can breake all formal frames we are putting it in. In particul, it breaks categorical frames easily.

Comment: Six months later... Why the downvotes to this rather restrained and fully on-topic answer? This is not meta, where votes indicate dis/agreement with the answer. The view expressed in this answer might displease categorists but it is routinely heard (often more forcefully uttered) in various mathematical circles. Why kill the messenger? Instead, downvoters might have answered a comment made to another answer and left hanging: "A.: It's in the software engineering textbooks [note the plurals]. Q: Can you point to one such textbook? [note "one"]" A.: no answer, so far.

Comment: @Did I didn't downvote, but I didn't upvote either: this answer asserts non-existence of applications, which by its nature cannot be backed by evidence.

Comment: @Zhen Lin: my answer is based on my own observations. It is thus an empirical fact, not an absolute statement (contrary to your opinion). If you claim that my assertion based on observations is wrong, then please support your opinion with evidence, i.e., real examples of applications of category theory in engineering. If you are not able to provide such examples (and after six months noone provided them here...), then it is just another premise to believe that my assertion is true.

Comment: I did not assert that category theory has applications in engineering either. I have not upvoted or downvoted _any_ of the answers in this question as such.

Comment: @ZhenLin "Non-existence of applications, by its nature, cannot be backed by evidence"... Hmmm... Sorry but this is a tiny bit too postmodern for my taste.

Comment: Sorry for being so direct, but this answer is misguided. It reproduces the usual prejudice on category theory, but nothing else. (1) "Category theory is a good and powerful language capable of expressing various concepts of purely algebraical nature." not just algebraic nature. Category theory has immersed into nearly *all* fields of pure and applied mathematics, and has serious applications to physics and computer science.

Comment: (2) "But it is a terrible tool for actually solving problems." This is not true. Category theory is abstract, sure, but this just means that it solves problems on a higher level. For a very basic example, limits and colimits in your favorite category provide useful techniques for constructing or decomposing your favorite objects. Obstruction theories are useful for, well, solving concrete obstructions for constructions such as lifting cohomology classes, and their theory heavily depends on category theory. The list of categorical methods useful for problems is endless.

Comment: (3) "I doubt you will find any such proof [using category theory in a non-linguistic way]." Well, mathematics is a vast language, right? You are happy with the concept of an abelian group? Assume that you prove a number-theoretic result using abelian groups (which is quite common). Would you qualify this as purely linguistic? Probably not. So what is the difference to proofs which use category theory in a crucial way?

Comment: (4) "Thus it is hardly a surprising fact that you will not find any serious application of category theory in engineering problems." Perhaps there is no serious application at the moment, but this doesn't mean that there won't be any in the future. Who knows? I don't have enough enough background to judge their applicability, but a google search reveals several papers which use category theory in the context on engineering, for example "Morphisms for resistive electrical networks" by L.H. Harper and John Baez's slides on "Network theory".

Comment: (Remember that the first computers were "constructed" on a sheet of paper, by Alan Turing, as a pure theoretical object! Now look at computers today ...)

Comment: (5) "Category theory fights with problems originating in category theory, with problems of no practical relevance for mathematicians" is far from being true. Just look at any modern paper on algebraic topology, in particular homotopy theory, algebraic geometry, abstract algebra, and you probably will find some category theory in it. It is probably the unique theory which holds all different branches of mathematics together (in conjunction with mathematical logic, perhaps).

Comment: Yesterday I've found a nice application of the concept of a natural transformation. The paper "The Riesz Representation Theorem Revisited" by Hartig uses this concept to give a proof of the Riesz Representation Theorem (a connection between Borel measures and continuous linear functionals on continuous functions). Naturality is used to reduce the general statement from compact Hausdorff spaces to extremally disconnected spaces, in which case there are enough continuous characteristic functions. Is this just a linguistic application? In any case, it is very useful for finding the proof.

Answer (score 5):

This too is a late answer, but in case anyone is still interested, [here](https://golem.ph.utexas.edu/category/2007/11/category_theory_and_biology.html) is a discussion with links about the use of category theory in biology/bioinformatics and genetics.  Also, while not specifically a book on applications of category theory, the book Conceptual Mathematics by William Lawvere (an undergrad book, so not super advanced, but still a very nice read) takes a practical-minded approach to categories.

Answer (score 1):

The state-of-the-art real world dimensionality reduction technique UMAP is based among other things on category theory:

https://arxiv.org/abs/1802.03426

https://github.com/lmcinnes/umap